# Create locked content per member on WordPress site.

Tags: wordpress

How can I create a portal where each individual member only has access to their specific files when logged in. We would like to use WordPress as the CMS. Customers can then access their own certification files instead of calling in each time they need access.

Comment: Since all uploaded files in WordPress are public because they are in the `wp-content/uploads` directory this wouldn't be as easy. You could however encode files as `base64` and save them in the database. Can you elaborate a bit more about how you imagine it?

Comment: We envision a portal where customers can log in and view their certifications online. They can then download, print, and view their specific certifications. We certify gauges for industrial use. Currently, to access a certification if the original paper copy is lost they must call our customer service. We want to remove this step for the customer. But they can't have access to other customer files.

Comment: Allright so that means you can't use regular uploads for WordPress because they are all public. You could make a metabox that encodes files as base64 and saves them in meta fields of posts that are somehow associated with specific users.